How to view the file information of table in PieCloudDB 2.12?
I recently upgraded the PiecloudDB database version from 2.8 to 2.12. Before I upgraded, I could view the file information of each table through the auxiliary table under pg_ostore. But now I find that there are no these auxiliary tables under pg_ostore, so how can I get the file information of each table now?

PiecloudDB provides a more convenient method to view table file information from version 2.9 onwards:
First, create pdb_internal_tools in the target database, then use the function pdb_get_relation_blocks_by_name or pdb_get_relation_blocks to view the file information of the table.
create extension pdb_internal_tools;

select * from pdb_get_relation_blocks_by_name('table_name');

or
select oid,relname from pg_class where relname='table_name';

select * from pdb_get_relation_blocks('oid');

